# getting error as {"message":"sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo",..} while savings scheduled job in jasperserver

Tags: jasperserver

When I am trying to save the scheduled job in jasper server  I am getting exception as 
[image]
Failed to save scheduled job.
The reason is: unexpected.error

The full response from the server is:

```
{"message":"sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo","errorCode":"unexpected.error","parameters":["com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSExceptionWrapper"]}.
```

I am setting the timezone as Europe/Helsinki - Eastern European Time.

The log file says the following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo 
  at org.hibernate.type.BlobType.set(BlobType.java:72) 
  at org.hibernate.type.BlobType.nullSafeSet(BlobType.java:140)
  at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:777)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1165)
        at org.hibernate.action.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:60)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:280)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:171)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:322)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1028)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$28.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:885)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:407)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:375)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.flush(HibernateTemplate.java:888)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.hibernate.HibernateReportJobsPersistenceService$1.execute(HibernateReportJobsPersistenceService.java:165)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.HibernateDaoImpl.executeWriteCallback(HibernateDaoImpl.java:84)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.HibernateDaoImpl.executeWriteCallback(HibernateDaoImpl.java:74)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.hibernate.HibernateReportJobsPersistenceService.saveJob(HibernateReportJobsPersistenceService.java:146)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.hibernate.HibernateReportJobsPersistenceService.saveJob(HibernateReportJobsPersistenceService.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1009.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy80.saveJob(Unknown Source)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.ReportSchedulingFacade.scheduleJob(ReportSchedulingFacade.java:516)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor996.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy81.scheduleJob(Unknown Source)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.services.impl.JobsServiceImpl.scheduleJob(JobsServiceImpl.java:88)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.job.JobsJaxrsService$5.call(JobsJaxrsService.java:226)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.job.JobsJaxrsService$5.call(JobsJaxrsService.java:224)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.job.JobsServiceCallTemplate.callRemoteService(JobsServiceCallTemplate.java:53)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.job.JobsServiceCallTemplate.callRemoteService(JobsServiceCallTemplate.java:42)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.common.RemoteServiceWrapper.callRemoteService(RemoteServiceWrapper.java:44)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.job.JobsJaxrsService.scheduleJobWithProcessedParameters(JobsJaxrsService.java:224)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor995.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1354)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:709)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:85)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:44)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:145)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:151)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:218)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:44)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:218)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.filter.BasicLoggingFilter.doFilter(BasicLoggingFilter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.JSCsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(JSCsrfGuardFilter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.WebAppSecurityFilter.doFilter(WebAppSecurityFilter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:44)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.encryption.EncryptionFilter.doFilter(EncryptionFilter.java:150)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:193)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.SessionDecoratorFilter.doFilter(SessionDecoratorFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.httpheaders.ResourceHTTPHeadersFilter.doFilter(ResourceHTTPHeadersFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.P3PFilter.doFilter(P3PFilter.java:44)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)>
```

<29-06-2016 13:03:04 EEST>     <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1467194584477>  <2016-06-

Comment: Please check `/tomcat/webapps/jasperserver[-pro]/WEB-INF/logs/jasperserver.log` for entries connected to this error and [edit] your question with the infos - if any.

Comment: Hi tobi6, Thanks for the reply. I have deployed the jasper war file on weblogic server. I am not using tomcat.. So the error I am getting is 

:java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo
            at org.hibernate.type.BlobType.set(BlobType.java:72)
            at org.hibernate.type.BlobType.nullSafeSet(BlobType.java:140)

Comment: I edited the question with the stack trace. Sometimes it also says what class the conversion is tried to. Is the stacktrace any longer? Did you use another database than the usual db? Was the date selected from the calendar popup or entered manually?

Comment: Date is selected from Calendar popup. as shown in the above picture attached.

Comment: I am using DB2 database connected to run the report. report is running fine when run on server . but while scheduling it is creating problem. I have the logs available but not sure howto attach here.

Comment: Tobi6, I have attached additional logs as well.

Comment: So you use db2 for *reports* and/or for the *internal Jasperserver admin database*? This seems to be a db related error but I haven't seen it before. The logs unfortunately didn't help me.